Pyspark code to create a new column in existing dataframe and assign value to the column from a function
I have a dataframe df which has around 40 columns. Now I want to add a new column named as comment in the dataframe, and value of that column should be coming through a function.
I have created this function -
def new_column(df):
   null_cols = []
   for c in df.columns:
       if df.select(c).first()[0] == '':
           null_cols.append(c)
   if len(null_cols) > 1:
       x= (' & '.join(null_cols))
   else:
       x = (null_cols)
   return x

Calling the function here -
df_updt = df.withColumn("comment", new_column(df))

But I am getting error -
Argument col should be a Column, got str.
Is there any way this can be achieved in databricks?
I tried different version of the same function, I tried creating an udf, but udf dont take dataframe as an input parameter. I tried some other option that gemini provided, but nothing is working.
Please ignore the quotes in the function, that I had given otherwise stackoverflow was showing error.

It looks like you want to add a column, which specifies the null columns in the current row. This is one way to do it:
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 3), ("b", None), (None, None)], ["id", "count"])

+----+-----+
|  id|count|
+----+-----+
|   a|    3|
|   b| null|
|null| null|
+----+-----+

added_columns = []
for column in df.columns:
    added_columns.append(f"is_{column}_null")
    df = df.withColumn(
        f"is_{column}_null",
        when(df[column].isNull(), lit(str(column))).otherwise(lit(None)),
    )
df = (
    df.withColumn("null_columns", array(*added_columns))
    .drop(*added_columns)
    .withColumn(
        "null_columns",
        array_join(expr("filter(null_columns, x -> isnotnull(x))"), " & "),
    )
)
df.show()

+----+-----+------------+
|  id|count|null_columns|
+----+-----+------------+
|   a|    3|            |
|   b| null|       count|
|null| null|  id & count|
+----+-----+------------+

